# How to count frequency of a character in multiple cells within a column?

Tags: excel

kindly assist with the following question.

I need to count the frequency of a character in a group of cells within a column.  For example:

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|

John   |Smith  |

Joey   |Spark  |

Fran   |Chung  |

Bart   |Smolt  |

Adam   |Ebert  |
```

So basically I need an Excel function that will count the number of occurrences of the letter `J` in `Column A` ... Or count the occurrences of the letter `r` in `Column B`.

I tried using the following `function: =COUNTIF(A1:A5,"J")` ... But that doesn't seem to be working for me because the cell does not contain only `J` rather, the `J` is part of a string so the above function returns a 0 when I try to use.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

-Kash

Answer (score 1):

E.g:

```
=SUM(LEN(A1:A100))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1:A100),"J","")))
```

Is an array formula, so enter using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Don't need the UPPER() if you want it to be case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I can't seem to get the formula you've provided to work - likely because i'm still at an intermediate level with Excel.  Another thing I thought of was doing a CTRL-F on the selected range of cells.  For example, if I highlight the ColumnA in my example and do a CTRL-F to find "J" , excel will indicate 2 found and take me to the two instances of J.  I basically need to do this, but over multiple columns of data searching for one alphabet in each column.  Any other suggestions please, or a simplified version of the formula if possible - please.

Comment: Someone else might have a simpler formula - that was my best attempt...

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help though - greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Insert an asterisk * before and after the letter you are searching for as a wildcard to count the number of cells containing the letter.

**Note: as Ron mentioned this won't count the number of occurrences if it is in the same cell multiple times.

[Microsoft Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214153/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-number-or-text-in-a-range-in-excel)

Comment: If there were two of the letter in a single cell, it would only be counted once.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this will be a bit simpler formula,

in `C4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A4:A8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4:A8,"J","")))
```

in `D4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B4:B8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4:B8,"r","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow awesome !! This is perfect !! Thank you very much works perfectly !! Really appreciate your help !!